# awk - calculate percentages if condition is met

Tags: awk

I am starting with `awk` and don't know exactly how to calculate a percentage if a certain condition is met.

This is the file I'm using:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
```

I want to calculate the percentage based on the conditions:

- `native_lang` = 'finnish'
- `other_lang` = 'swedish'

The script I wrote is the following:

```
awk -F ',' {$4~/finnish/ && $5~/swedish/}END{for (i in a)}
```

The expected output given these rows should be `44.44%`

I couldn't find the way to add '+1' a variable that calculates de total.

How could it be done?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure to include languages whose names are substrings of other languages as that's a test case many scripts (like the one in your question) might fail for, e.g. `Romani` vs `Romanian` or `Russian` vs `Prussian`). Some languages are also multiple words (e..g. `West Frisian` or `Old Prussian`) so also show how those would be represented in your date or state if you don't allow those in your data.

Comment: What is `a`? You never added anything to an array.

Comment: Why can't you find a way to add 1 to a variable? Just use `variable++`.

Comment: I'd expect 55.55% -- records 0, 2, 3, 4, 8 match the criteria.

Comment: I'd suggesting reading the awk info page to get a better feel for the syntax of the language: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment a variable with `++` to get the count of matches. At the end divide by `NR-1`, which is the number of input rows (excluding the header).

The condition for executing a block doesn't go inside the `{}`, it goes before.

The script argument needs to be in quotes.

```
awk -F ',' '$4~/finnish/ && $5~/swedish/ {count++} 
            END {printf("%.2f%%\n", 100*count/(NR-1))}' filename.csv
```

Comment: if you put the languages within boundaries then it won't fail for overlapping languages like `romani` and `romanian`. In any awk you could do `$4 ~ /(^| )finnish( |$)/` or `(" "$4" ") ~ / finnish /`, and ditto for $5.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- objective is to calculate the percentage of input lines that match a given `native/other` language pair match
- input delimiter is a comma
- the `native` match is on the 4th input field
- the `other` match is on a word in the 5th input field (multiple words are separated by white space)
- comparisons should be case-insensitive
- there are five matches for `finnish/swedish` in the sample input so the result should be `55.56%` (as opposed to the `44.44%` suggested by the OP)
- do not need to worry about a language made up of multiple words (re: EdMorton's comment)
- there is no 'extra' white space next to the comma delimiters (otherwise we'll need to trim leading/trailing white space from the comma-delimited fields)

One `awk` idea:

```
native='finnish'
other='swedish'

awk -v native="${native}" -v other="${other}" -F"," '

BEGIN  { native = tolower(native)                 # convert everything to lower case
         other  = tolower(other)                  # to simulate case-insensitive matching
       }

FNR==1 { next }                                   # skip header; just in case "native" or "other" have a match in this line

tolower($4) == native {                           # case-insensitive match on field #4?

         n=split(tolower($5),a,"[[:space:]]")     # case-insensitive split of field #5 into components; should address EdMorton comment about substring matching multiple languages

         for (i=1;i<=n;i++)                       # loop through array looking for matches
             if (other == a[i]) {                 # and if found ...
                count++                           # increment our counter and ...
                next                              # skip to next input line; do not want to double count if there is a dupe in field #5
             }
       }

END    { if (NR >= 2)                             # as long as we have at least one data line ...
            printf "%.2f%\n", 100*count/(NR-1)    # print the % of input lines that match the "native/other" pair
       }
' users.dat
```

This generates:

```
55.56%
```